# Get An issue with SQL Query

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE salesman 
(
    salesmanid int, 
    name varchar(255), 
    city varchar(255), 
    commision int 
);  

INSERT INTO salesman (salesmanid,name,city,commision)
VALUES (5001, 'James Hoog', 'New York', .15),
VALUES (5002, 'Nail Knite', 'Paris', .13),
VALUES (5005, 'Pit Alex', 'London', .11),
VALUES (5006, 'Mc Lyon', 'Paris', .14),
VALUES (5007, 'Paul Adam', 'Rome', .13),
VALUES (5003, 'Lauson Hen', 'San Jose', .12);
```

ERROR:

> Syntax error at or near "VALUES"
> LINE 4: VALUES (5002, 'Nail Knite', 'Paris', .13),

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Typically just use `VALUES (...), (....), (.....) ` - don't repeat the `VALUES` keyword

Answer (score 1):

When inserting multiple rows at one time, write `VALUES` only once.

```
CREATE TABLE salesman (salesmanid int, name varchar(255), city varchar(255), commision int );  
INSERT INTO salesman (salesmanid,name,city,commision)
VALUES (5001, 'James Hoog', 'New York', .15),
 (5002, 'Nail Knite', 'Paris', 13),
 (5005, 'Pit Alex', 'London', .11),
 (5006, 'Mc Lyon', 'Paris', .14),
 (5007, 'Paul Adam', 'Rome', .13),
 (5003, 'Lauson Hen', 'San Jose', .12);
```

Answer (score 0):

can be done this way:

```
CREATE TABLE salesman (salesmanid int, name varchar(255), city varchar(255), commision int );  
    INSERT INTO salesman (salesmanid,name,city,commision)
    VALUES (5001, 'James Hoog', 'New York', .15);
    INSERT INTO salesman (salesmanid,name,city,commision)
    VALUES (5002, 'Nail Knite', 'Paris', .13);
    INSERT INTO salesman (salesmanid,name,city,commision)
    VALUES (5005, 'Pit Alex', 'London', .11);
    INSERT INTO salesman (salesmanid,name,city,commision)
    VALUES (5006, 'Mc Lyon', 'Paris', .14);
    INSERT INTO salesman (salesmanid,name,city,commision)
    VALUES (5007, 'Paul Adam', 'Rome', .13);
    INSERT INTO salesman (salesmanid,name,city,commision)
    VALUES (5003, 'Lauson Hen', 'San Jose', .12);
```

Or

```
CREATE TABLE salesman (salesmanid int, name varchar(255), city varchar(255), commision int );  
INSERT INTO salesman (salesmanid,name,city,commision)
VALUES (5001, 'James Hoog', 'New York', .15),
(5002, 'Nail Knite', 'Paris', .13),
(5005, 'Pit Alex', 'London', .11),
(5006, 'Mc Lyon', 'Paris', .14),
(5007, 'Paul Adam', 'Rome', .13),
(5003, 'Lauson Hen', 'San Jose', .12)
```